# Docker cannot resolve dns

Tags: docker, dns

I am building a postgres docker image taht goes like this :

```
FROM postgres:12.6-alpine

RUN apk add --quiet --no-cache curl tar python3 jq supervisor && \
    curl -Os https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-340.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf google-cloud-sdk-340.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    google-cloud-sdk/install.sh && \
    rm /google-cloud-sdk-340.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

ENV GLIBC_VER=2.31-r0

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

However when it gets to the point of :

```
curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk
```

It cannot resolve the DNS :

```
Could not resolve host: github.com; Name or service not known
```

Any idea why this may happen ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your DNS server configuration that you inherit from your host is broken.

Try setting changing the DNS configuration of your host to use google DNS server like so : [Google DNS server setup](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)